# ss command output explanation (the 3rd number in process description)

Tags: linux, sockets

What's the meaning of the 3rd parameter in parentheses in the output of `ss -u` (number 7 for nginx processes)?

```
LISTEN     0      128          127.0.0.1:80                  *:*     
users:(("nginx",1430,7),("nginx",1429,7),("nginx",1428,7),("nginx",1427,7),("nginx",1426,7))
```

Comment: Since `ss` is a tool that is mainly used for debugging network applications, it is most certainly on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the number of the file descriptor of the socket.  You can check this with

```
ls -l /proc/1430/fd/
```